# Dovecot ACL's, shared mailboxes and virtual domains

Tags: debian, email-server, dovecot, access-control-list, debian-jessie

I am struggling with ACL's, shared mailboxes and dovecot, and I really can't get it to work. I have gone through the official dovecot docs, searched the Internet for helpful howto's, to no avail.

I am certainly missing something.

Here follows my `doveconf -n` output. I have already tried many many many different "location" values within "namespace condivisa"…

It seems that ACL's are correctly set to the mailbox, but I cannot see the shared mailbox under the folder hierarchy in Thunderbird or Roundcube.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you will provide.

```
# 2.2.13: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64 Debian 8.3 ext4
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb
default_client_limit = 4099
default_process_limit = 1024
imap_client_workarounds = tb-lsub-flags
lda_mailbox_autocreate = yes
lda_mailbox_autosubscribe = yes
log_timestamp = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
mail_access_groups = vmail
mail_debug = yes
mail_gid = vmail
mail_location = maildir:/home/vmail/%d/%n
mail_plugins = acl
mail_privileged_group = vmail
mail_uid = vmail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
namespace condivisa {
  list = yes
  location = maildir:/home/vmail/%%d/%%n:INDEXPVT=~/CONDIVISA.%%u
  prefix = _CONDIVISA.%%u.
  separator = .
  subscriptions = no
  type = shared
}
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
  type = private
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  acl = vfile
  acl_anyone = allow
  acl_shared_dict = file:/home/vmail/%d/shared-mailboxes.db
  quota = maildir:User quota
  quota_rule = *:storage=1G
  quota_rule2 = Trash:storage=+100M
  quota_warning = storage=95%% quota-warning 95 %u
  quota_warning2 = storage=80%% quota-warning 80 %u
  sieve = /home/vmail/sieve/%d/%n/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_before = /home/vmail/sieve/globalsieverc
  sieve_dir = /home/vmail/sieve/%d/%n
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@xyz.com
protocols = " imap sieve sieve"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0660
    user = vmail
  }
}
service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 12272
  }
}
service quota-warning {
  executable = script /etc/dovecot/quota-warning.sh
  unix_listener quota-warning {
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
ssl = required
ssl_ca = </opt/ssl/ca.crt
ssl_cert = </opt/ssl/cert.crt
ssl_cipher_list = ALL:+HIGH:+TLSv1.2:+TLSv1.1:+TLSv1:+SSLv3:!LOW:!MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!EXP:!ADH:!SSLv2:!aNULL
ssl_key = </opt/ssl/private.key
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = acl quota sieve
}
protocol imap {
  mail_max_userip_connections = 256
  mail_plugins = acl quota imap_quota imap_acl
}
```